# Is there any evidence that R2-D2 has restored C-3PO's memory before?

Tags: star-wars

We saw in Episode 9 that R2-D2 had a (relatively recent) back-up of C-3PO's memory, and restored it near the end of the film.

We also saw that Bail Organa had C-3PO's memory wiped at the end of Episode 3. I'm assuming that he didn't have it restored, or he'd been blathering on about having been built on Tatooine by the guy Anakin.

But have there been any other times (any media source will do) where R2-D2 had to restore C-3PO's memory before Episode 9?  The fact that he keeps a copy of it implies that he's needed to in the past. (Also, the fact that he's got room for it suggests either that R2-D2's storage capacity is far larger than expected, or...well, that C-3PO's personality doesn't take up a lot of space...

Comment: I'm not sure that R2-D2 ever restored C-3PO's memory before Episode 9, but it makes sense that he "could have", given that R2 and 3PO have so much compatible software. The same way that R2 would regularly "back-up" his own memory, it's very likely that C-3PO was doing the same thing for his respective memory. So 3PO can restore R2's lost memory as well.

Answer (score -1):

There have been multiple times when the droids did missions. It's possible that happened? Maybe R2's "bleep booping" means something to the effect of:

> Hey, man, I *told* you we should've disabled that anti-Sith protocol *last* time!

But I honestly think it was just R2 being cautious. 3PO is, after all, very clumsy and accident-prone.